# Visual C++ service fails to compile against Windows SDK 8.1, missing ktmw32.h

Tags: windows-8, header, transactions, visual-c++

I have inherited the maintenance of a Visual C++ project that implements a Windows Service for talking to some custom hardware device.

When attempting to build the project against Windows SDK 8.1 it failed with the following error indicating missing include file ktmw32.h

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atltransactionmanager.h(22): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ktmw32.h': No such file or directory`

So I searched my PC for ktmw32.h, and found just one copy, located within Windows SDK 8.0, under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um`

If I copy `ktmw32.h` from SDK 8.0 to SDK 8.1 everything builds fine.

My question is:

1. Why am I getting the original compile error against Windows SDK 8.1? (Note it compiled fine against 8.0 and earlier.)
2. Is my little fix, copying the header file across, okay and safe? (Or is there a better solution?)

Comment: yes, very sorry I accidentally posted on the wrong site!

Comment: The [Kernel Transaction Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb986748(v=vs.85).aspx) is still part of the Windows API. Correspondingly, the `ktmw32.h` header can be found in my Windows 8.1 SDK installation (Nov 2014 update). I'd suggest reinstalling the latest version of the SDK instead of copying the file from another version.

Comment: I have reinstalled via the following chain of links but it did not produce the missing header file: https://msdn.microsoft.com/microsoft-sdks-msdn   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bg162891   https://www.microsoft.com/click/services/Redirect2.ashx?CR_EAC=300135395 
The linked sdksetup.exe is an online-download and install app. Perhaps it sees I already have (most) Windows 8.1 SDK installed and then skips some steps.
I will try again now selecting the the "Standalone" dowload, which should include all files.